# Unable to access members of a class; SegFault

Tags: c++, class, segmentation-fault

I have a program where I am setting up a closed hash table. In each Element of the Hash table, there is a Student class which holds varies members (name, id, year, etc.). I am simply trying to print out what has been added to my array, but I keep getting a SegFault, and I don't know why. It is only in my print function, though. I have copied the line of code to my other functions or put them in different classes, and they work there, but not when I try to print from my print function. I am at the end of my rope, trying to figure out why I can access the memory location of each member, but not it's actual value.

Here is my program:

main.cpp:

```
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>
#include "hash.h"

int main()
{
string temp1;
string temp2;
string temp3;
string temp4;
string temp5;
string temp6;

Hash h;

do{
cout << "set> ";
cin >> temp1;

//Checking for quit command.

if(temp1.compare("quit") == 0)
{
    return 0;
}
 //checking for add command.
else if(temp1.compare("add") == 0)
{
    cin >> temp2;
    cin >> temp3;
    cin >> temp4;
    cin >> temp5;
    cin >> temp6;
    Student *s1 = new Student(temp2, temp3, temp4, temp5, temp6);
    Element e1(s1);
    h.add(e1);
}
//checking for remove command.
else if(temp1.compare("remove") == 0)
{
    int r;
    cin >> r;
    h.remove(r);
}
//checking for print command.
else if(temp1.compare("print") == 0)
{
    h.print();
}
//Anything else must be an error.
else
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Error! "<< endl;
}
}while(temp1.compare("quit") != 0);
}
```

hash.h:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

// Student Class
class Student{
private:
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    string id;
    string year;
    string major;

public:

//Constructor
    Student(string a, string b, string c, string d, string e);
friend class Element;
friend class Hash;
};

//Element class
class Element{
    private:
            Student *data;
    public:
            int getKey();
    Student* getData();
    void printStudent();

//Constructor
           Element(Student *e)
    {
        data = e;
    };
friend class Hash;
};

class Hash{
private:
    Element **array;
public:
    void add(Element);
    void print();
    void remove(int);

//Constructor
    Hash()
    {
        array = new Element *[10];
    };
friend class Student;
};
```

hash.cpp:

```
#include "hash.h"

//The Constructor for Student
 Student::Student(string a, string b, string c, string d, string e)
{
firstName = a;
lastName = b;
id = c;
year = d;
major = e;

}

//getKey function for Element Class

int Element::getKey()
{
int key = atoi(getData()->id.c_str());
return key;
}

Student* Element::getData()
{
return data;
}

void Element::printStudent()
{
string c = data->firstName;
cout<< "(" << c << ")";
}

//The add command
void Hash::add(Element e1)
{
int x = e1.getKey()%10;
int i = 0;

if(array[x] == NULL || array[x]->getData() == NULL)
{
    array[x] = &e1;

}

else
{while(array[x] != NULL || array[x]->getData() != NULL)
{
    x=(x+(i*i))%10;
    if(array[x] == NULL || array[x]->getData() == NULL)
    {
        array[x] = &e1;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        i++;
    }
}}

}

//The remove command
void Hash::remove(int n)
{
Element e2(NULL);
for(int j = 0; j<10; j++)
{
    if(n == array[j]->getKey())
    {
        array[j] = &e2;
        cout << "true" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
cout << "false" << endl;
}
//The Print command
void Hash::print()
{   int k = 0;
while(k<10)
{
    if(array[k] == NULL)
    {
        cout << "(NULL)";
    }
    else if(array[k]->getData() == NULL)
    {
        cout << "(DEL)";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "(" << array[k]->getData()->firstName << ")";
    }
k++;
}
cout << endl;
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I need your main function too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have [dangling pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer).

This function gets a temporary copy of an `Element`, calling it `e1`.

```
//The add command
void Hash::add(Element e1)
{
```

It then stores the address of this [local variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_variable).

```
    array[x] = &e1;
```

And when `Hash::add` leaves scope, `e1` no longer exists.

```
}
```

`array[x]` now points to memory that is no longer `Element e1`.

The general problem you are facing is that you have designed a `Hash` class that maintains pointers to objects, but has little control or knowledge regarding when those objects get destroyed.

You will need to personally ensure that objects added to your `Hash` last at least as long as the `Hash` does.

Comment: Let's take it one step further and recommend `std::vector<Element>`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's a reasonable approach, although with homework-y questions, I try to *subtract* ideas, rather than *add*.  :)

Comment: But I do need to differentiate between NULL and DEL entries.

Comment: @SarahAwesome okay, I have removed that additional suggestion.  :)

Comment: I understand my problem now, but not how to fix it. I can't think of a way to ensure that my Hash array retains Element e1 outside of the add function?

Comment: @SarahAwesome try `void Hash::add(Element * e1)`.  That won't make a new temporary Element.

Comment: Ok, but in main.cpp, it really does not like it when I try to do
`Element *e1(s1);`

Comment: Nevermind! I don't know what I did (I've been changing so many things) but it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution for your problem could be to store Element instances in Hash by value not by pointers. So:

```
class Hash{
private:
    Element *array;
public:
    void add(Element);
    void print();
    void remove(int);

//Constructor
    Hash()
    {
        array = new Element[10];
    };
friend class Student;
};
```

Now when you store new element or remove existing you copy them:

```
array[x] = e1; // not &e1 anymore
```

This is not very good practice, but at least could change your program in some workable state with minimal changes.

Comment: I've been trying to do that, but I keep getting long lines of error code that make no sense to me. That's why I switched to an array of pointers in the first place.